# SQLite Android Не могу понять как правильно запрос составить

Tags: android, sqlite

Я хочу найти все записи из БД и записать их в РейЛист, метод к которому я обращаюсь в SQLiteData Helper выглядит следующим образом (я новичок), как мне правильно написать  и что должен метод возвращать по идеи?:

```
 public String searchAll (ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> Email, ArrayList<String> Password)
{

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts",null,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        int idColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
        int nameColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        int emailColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("email");
        int passwordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("password");
        do {
            names.add(cursor.getString(nameColIndex));
            Email.add(cursor.getString(emailColIndex));
            Password.add(cursor.getString(passwordColIndex));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
   cursor.close();

    db.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делал как-то так
  OH oh= new OH(cont, "data",null,1);
        ArrayList data=new ArrayList<>();

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = oh.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("data", new String[] { oh.KEY_ID,
                    oh.KEY_METRIC, oh.KEY_ROOL },null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor!=null){

        try {
            data.add(cursor.getString(2));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }catch (Exception e){
            break;
        }
    }
```

1 параметр метода query -название таблицы
2 список столбцов, ну или как там правильно они называются
А далее там параметры типо условия выбора группировки
Прочитайте тут[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka.html)